# Should we address odds-related topics in a generic way?

Tags: discussion

There are many questions involving the odds of getting a hand in certain conditions. If they involved the same hand they could be considered duplicates, but they do not, and the answers are similar but different.

But the topic is the same: people having troubles when calculating permutations and combinations. There are times when people plainly does not know those topics, and times when people forgot those topics despite having studied them some time ago.

The matter is that there are sites like statistics and math.SE that can address these topics, so my question is:

Is it appropriate and useful to discuss C and P here in a generic way, not specific to any poker hand but applicable as general knowledge to resolve future questions without trashing the site with questions being ultimately similar?

Comment: Do you mean to discuss combinatorics, without using poker as an example?

Comment: Poker would be the focus but the basics of c/p are generic, and seems few users here understand how and why it works.

Comment: Although poker would be the focus, no specific hand would be the focus. This in order to address that lot of similar questions...

Comment: If you can think of a question that this type of answer would be good for, then sure, go for it. Ask it yourself, then answer it yourself. Id just suggest trying it and seeing how the community respond. If it doesn't work, edit and try again. Id be interested to see this :)

Comment: I will try when back home. In fact I was working on a draft.

Comment: I did it. http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-calculate-poker-hand-probabilities/8078#8078.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway I did it. [This is the question with answer](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-calculate-poker-hand-probabilities/8078#8078).

If the question or answer does not seem clear enough please feel free to edit it or suggest edits.